# creating a complex macro using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a complex workbook that i need filtered using vba.

- I need to delete rows that have blank cells from column G.
- I then need columns C through G hidden.
- Then I need Column H filtered to delete all rows greater than 2.
- Finally I need Column I sorted from Largest to smallest.

This is what i have so far but It half way works and i don't want to use a command button. I want to be able to paste a document in here and the code automatically works it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Created by William Hinebrick 277096
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
      xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
      xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If (xRg.Areas.Count > 1) Or (xRg.Columns.Count > 1) Then
        MsgBox "You can only select one column per time", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    xRg.Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
    Set xRg = xRg.Range("A1").Offset(-1).Resize(xRg.Rows.Count + 1)
    xRg.Range("A1") = "Temp"
    xRg.AutoFilter 1, ">2"
    Set xRg = Application.Intersect(xRg, xRg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then xRg.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Created by William Hinebrick 277096
    Dim xRg As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each xRg In Range("G1:G10000")
            If xRg.Value = "" Then
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
        Next xRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Column_Hide()
'Created by William Hinebrick 277096
    Columns("C:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub

Private Sub Sort_Drop(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("I1").Sort Key1:=Range("I2"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

I would like to be able to use this daily as I will be pasting New spreadsheets to this worksheet to be filtered so I may concise the results

Comment: Can you post your input data and desired output?

Comment: If this actually is complicated, you need to tell us why. All of these tasks are pretty simple and each one (*individually*) has very specific how-to's on this site. Why does this not work for you? You need to elaborate

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but you shouldn't allocate the authoring to you and then have stuff like "Kutools for Excel" in the middle. That's not very nice towards the initial authors and a sort of plagiarism...

Answer (score 0):

This should do everything listed.

If you require it to perform everytime you copy data in, then the `Worksheet_Change`event from your 2nd sub is the way to go. But this means it also runs every other time you change something in your workbook. I'd personally simply assign a Keyboard shortcut to it. Seems the easiest way to go.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim i As Double
Dim lastrow As Double

  lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For i = lastrow To 2 Step (-1) 'delete empty G cells
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then Cells(i, 7).EntireRow.Delete
  Next

  lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

  For i = lastrow To 2 Step (-1) 'delete H >2
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8).Value > 2 Then Cells(i, 8).EntireRow.Delete
  Next

Columns("C:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'hide columns

Range("I1").Sort Key1:=Range("I2"), _
      Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom 'Sort by I descending order

End Sub
```